# Flutter , Centering TextFormField with others inside Row

Tags: flutter

I creating a custom `TextFormField` with other `Text` widget and align all center together.

Using `Row` with center without the value everything is on center.

However when value entered, because of `Expanded` of two, so the space is divided by two. **But my purpose is to make everything keep on center, even when typing**

Without `Expanded`, `TextFormField` is not allow to put inside `Row`. Kind a hard

[image]
[image]

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child:  TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
        inputFormatters: [
          DecimalTextInputFormatter(decimalRange: 2)
        ],
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20.sp
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "0.00",
          hintStyle: theme.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
            color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20.sp
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 5.sp,),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.sp),
        child: Text("AAA",
          style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
            color: Color(0xFF8A8A8E),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: You are trying to center `TextFormField` and `Text` after input the way it is aligning with hint text?

Comment: See my answer below using IntrinsicWidth. That should help get you started

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would probably build a custom widget using:

- Row
- Flexible
- [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html)
- TextField
- Text

  ```
  Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Flexible(
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: TextField(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Flexible(child: Text('AAA')),
                ],
              )
  ```

[image]